# How do I refer to a calendar object on MS Access form in VBA?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am trying Forms("FormName").CalendarName.Date but it isn't working -- what's the correct syntax? Is there a similar syntax for use in queries?

Comment: Which version of Access are you using?  The Calendar object has changed a bit.

Comment: I am using version 2010

Comment: Forms("FormName").CalendarName.Value, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: It's not outputting anything (I am debug.printing to make sure)

Comment: stick a **MsgBox "Date is: " & Forms("FormName").CalendarName.Value** in your code and see if the messagebox displays anything

Comment: Silly question, but you did change "FormName" and "CalendarName" to be the actual form name and calendar name you're using, right?  Don't laugh, I can't tell you how many times people haven't changed those...

Comment: Yes, I am using the actual names. I am also getting the calendar name by right clicking the object and going to "Properties"

Comment: Ooops!  OK, the form isn't being referenced properly.  If should be **Forms!FormName.CalendarName.Value**

Comment: I actually tried that as well, still blank

Comment: OK, I'm on a conference call at work, I'll have to test something when I get a chance.  I'll be back later on that.

Comment: Oh my god, I am an idiot. Apparently you have to press a day button on the calendar itself, as opposed to just filling in month and year at the top. It works after that.

Comment: LOL.  Yeah, sometimes that happens.  :o)

Comment: Appreciate the help, either way! Thanks